# What is the difference between perform_later and perform_async?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

According to ActiveJob docs to enqueue a job I should use `perform_later`. Sidekiq docs implement `perform_async`, but the ActiveJob part of the docs [suggests using `perform_later`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job). I've used `perform_async` previously in Rails, so do these differ in any way or is it just convention?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

ActiveJob is a wrapper around the most known background job gems to provide a base API to work with background jobs.

ActiveJob defines `perform_later`. Sidekiq defines `perfom_async`. Which method you use depends on how you implemente your workers. If you use ActiveJob workers then you must use `perform_later`, if you don't use ActiveJob and just go with plain Sidekiq workers then use `perform_async`.

Comment: Is one way of implementing the workers recommended over the other? Does `perform_async` provide something that `perform_later` doesn't? I imagine that if I needed to move from Sidekiq to different queuing backend then `perform_later` would be a better choice.

Comment: I'm not sure if both methods are 100% equivalent since the code is different, but I guess you'll have almost the same features. Don't overthink it, if you need something from `perform_async` that's not provided by `perform_later` you can surelly implement what you need. It's a good practice to use ActiveJob, you don't need to worry about the background processing method, just code with a single interface and change the provider. Of course you could just use Sidekiq with no ActiveJob in the middle, but it would be a problem for the future if you need to change to another processing method.

Comment: You can even have workers implemented with ActiveJob and other with plain Sidekiq if you really need some special Sidekiq-only feature.

Comment: Be careful with bolting on extra dependencies without a desired reason.  [ActiveJob decreases Sidekiq performance significantly](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#performance) so the trade off needs to be worthwhile.